# Querying metaData for TestCase

Tags: metadata, rally

I'm executing the following query using the 2.0 RestAPI, where typeName is "TestCase"

```
    QueryRequest queryRequest = new QueryRequest("TypeDefinition");
    queryRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("TypePath, Attributes,ElementName,AttributeType,Hidden,AllowedValues,StringValue"));
    queryRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("TypePath", "=", typeName));
```

and I'm getting back 2 types: "TestCase" and "ScheduledTestCase".  Shouldn't I just get back a single result for TestCase? And the TypePath values are different. I also don't see ScheduledTestCase in the WebServiceURL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like a defect to me.  ScheduledTestCase is an private, internal type that is not exposed via WSAPI, so I'm surprised that it is being returned from the TypeDefinition endpoint.  TestCase is definitely the type you want to use.

I'll file a defect and investigate this a bit more.  In the meantime you can add another QueryFilter with Restorable = true to filter out the extra invalid type definition.

Comment: A recent fix went out for TypePath so that only Test Case is returned in the query mentioned in the question. Scheduled Test Case should no longer be returned if you run the query on type definition. There's no need for any additional filters anymore.